# How to use ES6 modules with commonjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

Going round in circles here, I'm using a module called get-folder-size
https://www.npmjs.com/package/get-folder-size

This only works, it seems, inside an ES6 module. So I've found out how to do this, and created one. Now I need to import that into my commonjs app (`node v14`).

`const mymod = require('mymod.js')` now won't work because I can't require it

`import mymod from 'mymod.js'` won't work. Cannot use import outside a module

change to `mymod.mjs` doesn't help

add `{"type": "module"}` to `package.json` at my Node app's entry point as suggested by google, and now it's erroring about loads of stuff that it doesn't like.

So I started off with

**index.js**

```
const mymod = require('./mymod.js');
```

**mymod.js**

```
const getFolderSize = (await import('get-folder-size')).default;
const mymod = async (org) => {
    let size = await getFolderSize.loose('./');
    return size;
};
module.exports = { mymod };
```

and I've ended up (a dozen iterations later), with a still not working:

**index.js**

```
import mymod from './mymod.mjs';
```

**mymod.mjs**

```
import getFolderSize from 'get-folder-size';
const mymod = async (org) => {
    let size = await getFolderSize.loose('./');
    return size;
};
export default mymod;
```

I think that explains it at least.. it's late, and I don't really get what's going on - this used to all work so beautifully! Worse, everything that I can find to try and help solve this seems to be related to packaging front end apps  :/

Answer (score 2):

You can use an intermediary function to do all the process:

---

mid.js file:

```
async function loadModule(name) {
    const module = await import(name);
    return module.default;
}

module.exports = {
    loadModule
};
```

---

sample.js file:

```
const mid = require('./mid');

mid.loadModule('get-folder-size')
    .then(gfs => {
        gfs.loose('/Users/oscar.granada/development/personal/lit/tmp')
            .then(size => {
                console.log(size);
            });
    });
```

Comment: I think I've following... just trying to work out how to export that as a usable function! Like, without importing the gfs module everytime I use it...

Comment: Maybe you can use a memoization pattern to cache the module, but internally the dependency engine does that.